# Why does 4 | E(K) for Montgomery curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Given a Montgomery curve over some finite field $K$ in the form 
$E/K: by^2 = x^3 + ax^2 + x$ and using $E(K)$ for the $K$-rational points. I've just read that the number of points in $E(K)$ is always divisible by 4.

This is from crypto and usually it is assumed that $\operatorname{char}(K) \neq 2$ and $\neq 3$. In this specific case we also have $K = \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ for some prime $p$.

Can somebody tell me why this is the case or if I have overlooked something?

Comment: is $K$ a finite field ?

Comment: @mercio Yes, in this context it would be.

Comment: Are you sure about the claim ? $y^2=x^3+x^2+x$ has three points over $\Bbb F_2$.

Comment: @mercio Thanks, I've added some more info again.

Comment: are $a$ and $b$ in $K$ or in $\Bbb F_p$ ?

Comment: @mercio Yes, that's what $E/K$ means. $E$ is defined over $K$, i.e. $a,b \in K$.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from: [Montgomery: *Speeding the Pollard and Elliptic Curve Methods of Factorization*, Mathematics of Computation, Volume 48. Number 177, January 1987, pages 243–264](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1987-48-177/S0025-5718-1987-0866113-7/):

> [p. 260:]
>   $$\tag{10.3.1.1} By^2 = x^3 + Ax^2 + x$$
>   [p. 262:]
>
> Let $p$ be a prime which does not divide $B(A + 2)(A - 2)$.
>   Suyama [31] observes that the order of the group associated with
>   $(10.3.1.1)$ modulo $p$ will always be divisible by $4$.
>   If $B(A + 2)$ is a quadratic residue, then the point $(1, \sqrt{(A + 2)/B})$
>   has order $4$.
>   If $B(A - 2)$ is a quadratic residue, then the point $(-1, \sqrt{(A - 2)/B})$
>   has order $4$.
>   If $(A + 2)(A - 2)$ is a quadratic residue,
>   then the cubic has three linear factors,
>   and again there is a subgroup of order $4$.
>
> [p. 264:]
>
> 31. Hiromi Suyama, "Informal preliminary report (8)," 25 Oct. 1985

For easier understanding, note that:

- Doubling the mentioned points of order $4$
  gives the point $(0,0)$ of order $2$.
- The discriminant of the cubic's quadratic factor is $A^2-4$.
- If the cubic has three linear factors,
  then the three roots correspond to points of order $2$ which generate a
  subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Following the quoted snippet, further conditions are mentioned,
given by Suyama, ensuring the existence of points of order $3$,
hence of group order divisible by $12$.